# Sourcegear Vault is slowing down Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sourcegear-vault

I am finding Source Gear Vault Standard is making Visual Studio unbearably slow.
Every time I check out a file, or even save a checked out file, i'm waiting up to 10 seconds just for the file to save.
If i change vault to work in offline mode, the problem has instantly gone away.

Here is the software i'm running

- Windows 7 Pro x64
- Visual Studio 2012
- Sourcegear Vault Standard version 6.0.1.598 (Client and Server)

I have tried reinstalling the vault client, but this has made no difference.
Has anyone else experienced this, or got any suggestions ?

At the moment i'm working in offline mode, and at the end of my session going back to online mode to check everything in.

I am also running Visual Studio 2010.
This is using the same version of Vault and does not have the same issues.

Comment: Sourcegear support topic with no resolution: http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=19270&p=71323&hilit=2012+Visual+Studio+2012

Comment: Sourcegear have now informed me later today will be a new download which should resolve the problem. I will mark as solution if this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newly released version 6.1.0.531 resolves this issue.